# Pulse width for mark pulse

Tags: frequency, pulse

What is the pulse width for the mark pulse in an equal mark to space ratio pulse train operating at a repetition frequency of 5 MHz?

**The answer is suppose to be 100 ns** .But I didn't understand how to get the result.Can someone explain to me how to get the answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1/ What is the period time of a 5MHz signal. 2/ What does "equal mark to space ratio" mean for a signal timing. From the answer to those two questions you should be able to find your final answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 5MHz waveform has a period of 200ns ( T = 1/f)

If the waveform has equal mark space ratio, then the duty is 50%. The width of a pulse is therefore 50% of the total period

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!

Comment: @JarvisFerns Accept this answer using the checkmark on the left side of the answer. Click it to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)

Answer (score 1):

A frequency of 5MHz has a period of 200ns. That's divided into one mark and one space. If the mark and space durations are equal, then each is exactly half of 200ns.